# Can "mov eax,mem" occur with "lock inc mem" at the same time in multiprocessor?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, multiprocessing

in multiprocessor, we know in `lock inc mem`: lock can ensure no other operation can access the address `mem`.

but when one processor is executing `mov eax,mem` firstly, and then before it completed, second processor execute `lock inc mem`.

What will be the result?

1. Second instruction (`lock inc mem`) waits until the first (`mov eax,mem`) is completed? (as a result,first will get correct value)
2. Both instructions execute simultaneously. (as a result, first maybe get an unpredicted value)

Comment: I think it's still a race condition. If the processor with `mov eax,mem` already has it in cache, it's not even going to see the new value because the invalidation signal from the other processor's `lock` will take many more cycles to arrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mem is 32-bit aligned, the mov operation is guaranteed to be atomic. To quote volume 3A of the software developer's manual: "once started, the processor guarantees that
the operation will be completed before another processor or bus agent is allowed
access to the memory location"

Comment: lock inc [mem] if mem is not 32-bit aligned, can it sill work fine?

Comment: For instruction that use the `LOCK` prefix alignment shouldn't matter. As for the `MOV` - if the memory location is cached then the operation will still be atomic even it it's unaligned on Pentium Pro and later models (but keep in mind that unaligned accesses will decrease performance). If it's not cached then I'm not entirely sure if it will be implictly atomic or if you have to enforce it somehow.

Comment: thanks. In Application, I'll just assume `MOV` is atomic if not aligned. So, I'll try my best to keep it aligned.

Comment: The compiler should handle that for you automatically. About the only time you'd get unaligned data is if you explicitly move a buffer to an unaligned offset within an allocated chunk of memory.

Comment: generally compiler should align it, but we should suspect any thing. just personal view.

Answer (score 2):

The `mov EAX,[mem]` is atomic, in that it reads all bits in parallel. There is no chance of getting a partial result. Whether it gets the value before or after an update is not that important.

The `inc [mem]` is different, in that it both reads and writes to the memory location. If you have two of them running in parallel, the result will be unpredictable as one can overwrite the result of the other. Using a `lock` solves that by claiming the bus during the entire instruction. Everyone else will have to wait.